# ¿Como puedo utilizar un TextView fuera de mi MainActivity, en otra clase o función en Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Dentro de la Clase principal no hay problema.

Es fuera d la clase principal donde me da error

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
```

Así inicializo yo el TextView

```
lateinit val tv : TextView



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv)
    texview()

}





fun texview() {

tv.setText("texto")

}



}
```

Aquí es donde me da error

```
fun texview() {

tv.setText("texto")

}
```

Siempre me da error, ya sea dentro de una Clase o función. 
Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: que error te marca? es necesario que crees esa función? si vas a setear un textview puedes directamente hacerlo dentro del `onCreate()`

Comment: Ya lo resolví era problema de un hilo que cree, pero ya que estamos otra duda. Podría utilizarlo de la siguiente manera?:                                    val texto = MainActivity()
texto.tv.setText("texto")

Comment: debería irte sin problemas

Comment: Gracias, un saludo.